# left join or right join depending on data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am  in  a situation in which i need to join 2 tables but depending on datat i need sometimes to consider a table as primary and the other as joined, and viceversa.
I make a simple example to  recreate the situation, imagine i have 2 tables (temp tables here) in which tasks for an employee are contained:

`#JOB_TASKS` contains the tasks that deal with job for the employees

`#FAMILY_TASKS` contains the tasks that deal with family for the employees

if for `ID_EMPLOYEE = 1`, `#FAMILY_TASKS` has no records, while `#JOB_TASKS` has some records, `#JOB_TASKS` should be the main table and `#FAMILY_TASKS` the joined one. While if for `ID_EMPLOYEE = 2`, `#FAMILY_TASKS` has some records, but`#JOB_TASKS` has no records, `#JOB_TASKS` should be the joined table and `#FAMILY_TASKS` the main on.

Somehow these are the queries i have:

```
Select * 
FROM 
#FAMILY_TASKS FT LEFT OUTER JOIN
#JOB_TASKS JT ON JT.ID_EMPLOYEE = FT.ID_EMPLOYEE

--same query "right join" written as "left join":
Select * 
FROM 
#JOB_TASKS JT LEFT OUTER JOIN
#FAMILY_TASKS FT ON FT.ID_EMPLOYEE = JT.ID_EMPLOYEE
```

I would like to have a single query that does automatically the correct join. This could be done with a cursor, but how to perform this with a select statement?

I hope i expressed myself.

Comment: `union all` of both would give you some duplicates,  guess thatsa no-no?

Comment: Sample data and expected result would be nice here. i think i have an idea, however, I could be off base; so I'd like to test. Until then, consider using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for if you have an employee that has both family_tasks and Job_Tasks. If you have an employee with family tasks A & B, and Job Tasks C & D, how many result rows do you expect and what should they be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op hasn't updated their post, so this is a bit of a guess. I *think* this could be achieved with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, using the following logic:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID int = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM #FAMILY_TASKS FT
     FULL OUTER JOIN #JOB_TASKS JT ON JT.ID_EMPLOYEE = JT.ID_EMPLOYEE
WHERE @EmployeeID IN (FT.ID_EMPLOYEE,JT.EmployeeID);
```

Comment: Yes FULL JOIN is what i was looking for. I read about it 10 years ago when I studied on Robert Viera's Sql Server 2000 Programming book but then i forgot it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a FULL OUTER JOIN and some conditions.

In psuedocode, your conditions would do the following:

```
(ID_EMPLOYEE = 1 AND #JOBTASKS.Column IS NOT NULL)
OR 
(ID_EMPLOYEE = 2 AND #FAMILYTASKS.Column IS NOT NULL)
```